# Add additional claims on TokenValidated event

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-1.1

In my ASP.NET Core 1.1 application I'm using JWT tokens for authentication.
Under certain conditions I need to add additional claims to the user which are not provided in the token.

So I hooked into the `IJwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated` event and tried to add additional claims in that event handler. I tried several things:

```
// (1) - doesn't work
((ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity).AddClaim(myNewClaim);

// (2) - doesn't work
var jwtToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
((ICollection<Claim>)jwtToken.Claims).Add(myNewClaim);

// (3) - doesn't work
context.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { myNewClaim }));
```

No matter how I do it, I don't see these additional claims in `User.Claims` in the controller action.

What is the correct way to add additional claims after successful bearer token verification?

Comment: The token is generated by an external system. That's why I need to append the claims on token verification (unfortunately....)

Comment: Even though for ASP.NET Core 2.0, does [Adding custom claims to a user during authentication](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) help?

Comment: JWT cannot be modified once they are issued if you are trying to append a claim to an existing JWT, you could issue a new JWT using JWTSecurityToken and the payload form the received token.

Comment: @MarkG: Thanks for that link. In ASP.NET Core 1.1 the context object does not contain a `Principal` field. The closest I could find is `context.HttpContext.User` which gives me access to a `ClaimsPrincipal` object. That would lead us back to my third attempt above, which doesn't work.

Comment: @rahicks: I'm not trying to modify a JWT. I'm trying to add additional claims to the user once the token has been validated.

Comment: @RobertHegner See [Access the JWT bearer token when using the JWT middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/).

Comment: @MarkG Thank you so much for this link. Accessing `context.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity` did the trick! Feel free to provide that as an answer, so that I can accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article linked by @MarkG shows a fourth way for accessing the claims - and this one works:

```
// (4) - works!
(context.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(myNewClaim);
```